# Why do I get 'this.setData is not a function' in my prototype function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

A while back I created a dialogue function by using `Prototype`. The code looks like this:

```
//Dialog constructor
var sldialog = function(params, callback){
    this.box         = // (...)
    this.background  = // (...)
    this.buttonPanel = // (...)
    this.callback    = callback;
    this.options     = $.extend({
     // (...)
    },params);

    this.setData();
    this.showDialog();
    this.dialogboxAction();
};

// Dialog functions
sldialog.prototype = {
    setData: function(){ (..) },
    showDialog: function(){ (..) },
    dialogboxAction: function(){ (..) },
};
```

I call the function using the following code:

```
    sldialog({
        title: 'Delete peprson',
        msg: 'Do you really want to delete this person?',
        type: 'action',
        yes: 'Delete person',
        multiDialog: 1
    }, function (confirmed) {
      // (...)
    });
```

Now I'm getting the error: `this.setData is not a function`.
I don't have to much experience on using `prototype` as I made this by looking at some tutorials.

This has been working fine up till now. I can't see how changes other places in the code affects this.

Comment: print this.setData before calling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sldialog` function is a *constructor* function; you call constructor functions via `new`. So you need to add that to where you're calling it:

```
new sldialog({
    title: 'Delete peprson',
    msg: 'Do you really want to delete this person?',
    type: 'action',
    yes: 'Delete person',
    multiDialog: 1
}, function (confirmed) {
  // (...)
});
```

The reason is that even though we call them "constructor functions," it's not the function that creates the object, it's the `new` operator. `new` creates the object, assigns the prototype, and then calls the constructor function with `this` referring to the new object.

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor function names are initially-capped. So perhaps `SLDialog` or `Sldialog` or `SlDialog` rather than `sldialog`.

---

Side note 2: In general, I discourage people from *replacing* the object that the function's `prototype` property points to; instead, I recommend just adding to it:

```
sldialog.prototype.setData = function() { ... };
sldialog.prototype.showDialog = function() { ... };
sldialog.prototype.dialogboxAction = function() { ... };
```

(And yes, it gets repetitive, so I usually have a function for copying properties to it.)

If you like, though, you can continue to replace it; just be sure to set `constructor` back to what it was defaulted to on the old object:

```
sldialog.prototype = {
    constructor: sldialog,              // <===
    setData: function(){ (..) },
    showDialog: function(){ (..) },
    dialogboxAction: function(){ (..) },
};
```

That way, you ensure that the prototype's backlink to the constructor function is maintained.